# extract year, mounth and day from a date using eclipselink jql

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am sending a date from a primefaces calendar to backing bean. The object that primefaces send is Date.

```
<p:calendar id="exact_Date" value="#{h.model.arhExactDate}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"/>
```

The date in debugger looks like Thu Mar 02 00:00:00 EET 2017.

I want to extract from this only the date part (withowt time) and compare it with a timestamp from the database **like** 2017-03-02 18:57:19.152 using eclipselink jpql.

So it will be something like: cast(2017-03-02 18:57:19.152 as varchar) like 2017-03-02 18 where the part after "like" is the date prat from the date.

Looking at this [basic eclipselink guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL) I see that I can use extract method like: **extract(year from my_date)**. But how can I extract all I need?

I tried the query below but is not a valid expression:

```
select e from MyEntity e where  extract(year from e.reqDate) = :extract(year from exactDate)
```

If it worked, I would have liked to have something like:

```
 extract(year,mounth,day from e.reqDate) =:(exactDate)
```

I don't want something like: 
    extract(year from e.reqDate) = :extract(year from exactDate) and  extract(month from e.reqDate) = :extract(month from exactDate) and  extract(day from e.reqDate) = :extract(day from exactDate)

Comment: The eclipseLink guide shows the format as "EXTRACT(YEAR, e.startDate)".  Yours seems different.  have you tried just "select e from MyEntity e where  extract(YEAR, e.reqDate) = :year_parameter" ? What is the error or generated SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to pass in a date object and only compare the date values excluding the time portion, you might try using TruncateDate or Trunc options in JPQL:

```
"select e from MyEntity e where truncateDate(e.reqDate) = :dateParameter"
```

TRUNC is on most databases and if not given a year/month/day paramater should default to stripping out the time.  It can be accessed in other providers using JPQL's FUNCTION:

```
"select e from MyEntity e where FUNCTION('TRUNC', e.reqDate) = :dateParameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect EclipseLink to support the following vendor extension JPQL functions

```
MONTH(field)
YEAR(field)
DAY(field)
```

Note that these are not JPA standard, but most JPA providers support them. Check the manual for your provider. "extract" is an SQL function only that would only work in SQL on very few databases, so best avoided